# Sharepoint Online CSOM Powershell - Remove Permission level for a Group in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, custom-list, groups, csom

I have a list in which I want to remove "Contribute" Permission Level for a particular group "List Members Group". After removing this, I want to add "Read" Permission level.

Basically, I want the users of this group to have "Read" for this list.
Here's the code which is not working for me.

```
#Get the list
       $list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("EmployeesList")
       $ctx.load($list)
       $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Break Role Inheritence
       $list.BreakRoleInheritance($true, $false) 

#Get the Members Group
        $memberGroup=$web.AssociatedMemberGroup
        $ctx.Load($memberGroup)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get the role assignment for the particular Group
         $roleAssign  = $list.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal($memberGroup);
         $ctx.Load($roleAssign)

#Get the role definition for the particular Group
         $roleDefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Contribute")
         $ctx.Load($roleDefinition)

#Remove the role
           $roleAssign.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove($roleDefinition);
           $ctx.Load($roleAssign)

$roleAssign.Update()
$list.Update();
```

I want to remove the existing "Read" Permission Level for the Group(that too only for this list)

Please suggest where am I going wrong.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is Read the only permission this group has? Do you want to remove entire group it self from the item level?